# Different tabulator size of TextView on different screen densities

Tags: android, textview, size

I'm testing my layout on a Nexus S (hdpi with 480x800) and Nexus 4 (xhdpi with 768x1280).

I have a TextView with `android:textSize="12sp"` where I want to put two lines of text from the strings.xml.
The result should look like this:

```
    Portion 1 = Something here
                some other line
```

In strings.xml it looks like this:

```
    <string name="some_text">Portion 1 =\tSomething here\n\t\t\t\t\tsome other line</string>
```

Now, on Nexus S, the text indent looks as it should, but on Nexus 4 it looks like this:

```
    Portion 1 = Something here
             some other line
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't the tablulator(\t) have the same size on both devices? Also, it's the same (default) font from android and I have not changed the devices text size.

Thanks,
Norbert